# Radeditor on google chrome not working

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, telerik, disabled-control, radeditor

I have a telerik rad editor. My application runs in .net 2.0 environment. The telerik version is : 2012.3.1016.35. The rad editor is not enabled on chrome only. I cannot type into it.Works fine in all other browsers. Upgrading to new telerik is not an option. Because this is an old client and changing will/may affect other styling things. 
So what are my options. I posted this on telerik, but no response. If you need more information, please let me know. Thanks.

**EDIT:**
ON checking the console I got an error. Please find the image attached to see the error.
[image]

SOLUTION:
I got it. I had a line like below to open a rad window:

```
rwSC.VisibleOnPageLoad = True
```

This was causing the problem. Sometimes it would open fast and the control would load and I can place my cursor within the rad editor within the rad window and sometimes cannot. So I replaced that with this

```
Javascript.RegisterStartupScript(Me, "NewSC", "setTimeout(""$find('" & rwSC.ClientID & "').show();"", 500);", True)
```

And now it works. The rad editor within the radwindow is enabled and I can edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you have: http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/108/Feedback/Details/125713?
If so, try the JS workaround there